# Footer on mobile screen sizes

Tags: html, css

This is driving me mad, I have tried every possible solution that I know and others that I have found on SO, but I must be missing something.

I have a site that has a footer in absolute position which works wonders on desktop, however when I go to view on a mobile screen size the footer jumps to all sorts of places depending on how I set the CSS position for it, see my code below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Serif, sans-serif;
}
/*background:rgb(255,224,240);*/

#logo {
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#nav {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 28%;
}
footer {
  width: 60%;
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
li:hover a {
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
.important {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
#left_page {
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
#right_page {
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
#centre_block {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 6%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 99%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  #body {
    padding-bottom: 5%;
  }
  #nav {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 28%;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!--60% width-->
  <header>
    <div id="logo" class="logo">
      <h1>This is where the logo will be</h1>
    </div>
    <!--50% centred-->
    <div id="nav">
      <!--50% width centred-->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="left_page" class="columns">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="right_page" class="columns">
    <h2>Sed efficitur consequat massa ut sagittis.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="centre_block">
    <h1>Sed dapibus dapibus lectus in auctor.</h1>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h3>This will be the footer</h3>
    <p>This is where &copy; Copyright information goes</p>
  </footer>

</div>
```

I have been pulling my hair out all day on this now, can someone assist?

Thanks

Comment: It's a height issue. Works fine at all widths. When the window height is too small, then it's breaking down.

Comment: @AndyM I thought it was, but cannot figure out why or how

Comment: @Ramis Wachtler, thanks for editing, as the original is how i Write CSS and understand not every one reads it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

1.) Height of footer = 5% of screen size. The text content overflows it.

2.) Body and HTML don't have declared heights.

3.) Your content inside `#wrapper` is floated, and there isn't a clearing element after.

4.) Your footer is going to always be visible, which will overlap content.

---

### Fixes

1.) Remove `height:5%;` from `footer`.

2.) Add this line of CSS: `html, body {height:100%;}`

3.) Add a pseudo-element after `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

3.) If `html` and `body` are always `100%` of window height, then you can set the `#wrapper` to `min-height:100%` and `position:relative`. This will act as a catch-all for absolutely positioned elements. They will appear at the bottom of the wrapper, which will either be the bottom of the screen, or further down, depending on content length. We'll also need to add a bit of padding to the bottom of the wrapper to prevent overlay, and make sure that `box-sizing` is set to `border-box` so that the overall height is still 100%. (Could also use calc())

---

### Screencast With Changes

[image]

### Working Code

I fixed all of these in the snippet below, and highlighted the footer with a red background so that you can see.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Serif, sans-serif;
}
/*background:rgb(255,224,240);*/

html, body {
  height:100%;
}
#logo {
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:60px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#wrapper:after {
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  content:"";
}
#nav {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 28%;
}
footer {
  width: 60%;
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
li:hover a {
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
.important {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
#left_page {
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
#right_page {
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
#centre_block {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 6%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 65, 180);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 99%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  #body {
    padding-bottom: 5%;
  }
  #nav {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 28%;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!--60% width-->
  <header>
    <div id="logo" class="logo">
      <h1>This is where the logo will be</h1>
    </div>
    <!--50% centred-->
    <div id="nav">
      <!--50% width centred-->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="left_page" class="columns">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="right_page" class="columns">
    <h2>Sed efficitur consequat massa ut sagittis.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="centre_block">
    <h1>Sed dapibus dapibus lectus in auctor.</h1>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h3>This will be the footer</h3>
    <p>This is where &copy; Copyright information goes</p>
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will make these changes and see how they work. I have only ever previously worked on single page scrolling sites so not 100% used to these layouts

Comment: The alternative is to just keep the footer fixed at the bottom of the screen at all times. Just remove the `position:relative` from `#wrapper`.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, I knew I was missing things

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to the wonderful world of web development.

Remark 1: Html is single threaded and things are stacked from top to bottom. "Position: Absolute" takes this element outside of the grid, therefore it's use here is pretty bad because then things ignore each other and cluster up.

Remark 2: When you float things be sure to either

1. Contain them within a parent element so the float doesn't apply to other elements
   **OR**
2. Add "Clear: left; or Clear: Right;" to the following element so that it doesn't float up (the footer floats up and ignores the existence of the previous divs)

Here is a slightly better code to get things running:

```
      *{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, 

Serif, sans-serif;}/*background:rgb(255,224,240);*/

#logo{width:45%;margin:auto;}

#wrapper{width:60%;margin:auto;height:100%;}

#nav{width:50%;float:left;margin:0;padding:0;margin-left:28%;}

footer{width:100%;height:5%; text-align: center; clear: left;}

ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}

li{display:inline-block;}

li a{display:block;padding:0 20px;height:50px;line-height:50px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-family:sans-serif;color:rgb(0,0,0);}

li:hover a{border-bottom:4px solid rgb(255,65,180);}

p{text-align:center;}

.important{text-align:left;margin-top:2%;margin-left:1%;margin-right:1%;margin-bottom:2%;}

h2{text-align:center;}

#left_page{width:48%;margin-top:6%;float:left;margin-right:3%;border:2px solid rgb(255,65,180);}

#right_page{width:48%;margin-top:6%;float:left;border:2px solid rgb(255,65,180);}

#centre_block{width:100%;float:left;margin-top:6%;border:2px solid rgb(255,65,180);}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){

    #wrapper{width:99%;min-height:100%;}

    #body{padding-bottom:5%;}

    #nav{width:50%;margin:0;padding:0;margin-left:28%;}

    footer{width:100%;height:5%;}
```

Basically I

- stopped the footer from sticking to the bottom by removing "bottom: 0;" which made it overlap other things in the smaller sizes (You really don't want a footer that scrolls with you)
- Removed #nav {float: left;} which allowed the following divs to overlap (you only want the li's to float.)
- Removed absolute positioning so things would be positioned AFTER the previous elements

Try rewriting a new website with these in mind.

Goodluck!
- Khaled Ali

Comment: Thanks for this. I will make these changes and see how they work. I have only ever previously worked on single page scrolling sites so not 100% used to these layouts